# ASUS Z97-A ATX Devil's Peak System Fails to Power-on

Tags: boot, desktop

I have a Devil's peak system for the last 6 years. I recently moved the box between rooms (gently) and now the power button does not work.

Symptom:

- push power button, no fan, no noise, no response
- light on motherboard is on so I know power goes to it; plugging in ethernet cable I see the ethernet lights turn on

Debug:

- tried swapping reset and power connectors. No change. Not a power switch issue
- tried removing DDR3 DIMMs, no change.
- tried cleaning/dusting and reseating connectors, no change.

I have not tried swapping the power supply. However, before I do that is there anything else I should look at? Note the power supply is an EVGA 750W. With (ironically) a 5 year warranty. Go figure that it died at around 7 years.

Comment: “Light on motherboard is on so I know power goes to it” - Which light?  I had a system I built, the standby light was on, system wouldn’t turn on.  Turned on the socket was dead.  Depending on the light it could be a lot of things.  They sell $10-15 PSU testers on Amazon.  They are a lot safer than a paperclip, but test the PSU, out of the case (or with absolutely nothing connected)

Comment: Or try a grounded extension cord to another outlet.